# How to get rid of Angular Template space highlights in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

How do I get rid of the space highlights in Angular / TypeScript / WebStorm 2019

[image]

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting looks as it should - it indicates a [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/using-language-injections.html#Using_Language_Injections.xml). If you don't like its green background, you can change the color in **Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General, Code / Injected language fragment** settings, **Background**:

[image]